# Regex match a line without a specific word

Tags: regex

I want to use regex to highlight the functions of a new programming language but i have a problem in EXCLUDING the functions that have the word "exported"
so

ok lines that I have to match examples:

```
routine hello
ROUTINE hello
   routine hello
   ROUTINE hello(a:INTEGER)
   routine hello (a   :  INTEGER)
   routine hello (a   :  INTEGER , b: STRING)
```

lines that I don't want to match examples:

```
   routine hello (a   :  INTEGER , b: STRING) exported
```

I've tried with

```
^[[:blank:]]*routine[[:blank:]]+([[:alnum:]_])+[[:blank:]]*([[:alnum:]_:,[:space:]]*)/^(?!.*exported)$/
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 13):

The following expression also does the trick:

```
^(?!.*exported).*$

|________________   line begin 
 |_______________   negative lookahead
    |____________   any characters
      |__________   your exclusion word
               |_   any characters
                 |_ end of line
```

Comment: Interpretation: `^(?!.*exported)`: "Make sure the line does not (`(?!)`) start out with (`^`) any 0 or more characters (`.*`) followed by 'exported'." `.*$`: "Select the entire line."

Answer (score 3):

You can use an expression like this to match all lines that don't contain the word "exported":

```
(?m)^(?!.*\bexported\b).*$
```

Comment: I will try, but it's important that is a "routine" an what parameters there are (if there are inside the brackets) beacouse i will put them in the output so i will have my "(non exported)function list"

Comment: Regarding the `?m`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27680097/what-does-ms-in-regex-mean https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html