# What does (?ms) in Regex mean?

Tags: regex, powershell

I have following Regex in Powershell :

```
[regex]$regex = 
@'
(?ms).*?<DIV class=row>.*?
'@
```

What does (?ms) mean here.

Comment: I understand it has something to do with Multiline/Single-line, but do not know much about how it works

Comment: The `m` modifier and `s` modifier are mutually exclusive. There is nothing in your regex `(?ms).*?<DIV class=row>.*?` that is affected by the `m` modifier.

Comment: FWIW, I believe I wrote the regex this is a fragment of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27649560/parse-through-related-tags-in-html/27651813#27651813.  The answer provided by @sln is a good explanation of why it was used.

Comment: @Arora - I got in too late to add much to the answers, but the way the question was framed, with just that fragment of the regex, it tended to create questions about  why it was there.  Hoped the thread link would provide some context and an example of how it might be used.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`(?m)` is the modifier for multi-line mode. It makes `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of a line, respectively, instead of matching the beginning and end of the input.

For example, given the input:

> ABC DEF
>   GHI

The regex `^[A-Z]{3}` will match:

> 1. `"ABC"`

Meanwhile, the regex `(?m)^[A-Z]{3}` will match:

> 1. `"ABC"`
> 2. `"GHI"`

`(?s)` is the modifier for single-line mode. It adds linebreaks and newlines to the list of characters that `.` will match.

Given the same input as before, the regex `[A-Z]{3}.` will match (note the inclusion of the space character):

> 1. `"ABC "`

While the regex `(?s)[A-Z]{3}.` will match:

> 1. `"ABC "`
> 2. `"DEF\n"`

Despite their names, the two modes aren't necessarily mutually exclusive. In some implementations they cancel out, but, for the most part, they can be used in concert. You can use both at once by writing `(?m)(?s)` or, in shorter form, `(?ms)`.

**EDIT:**

There are certain situations where you might want to use `(?ms)`. The following examples are a bit contrived, but I think they serve our purpose. Given the input (note the space after "ABC"):

> ABC
>   DEF
>   GHI

The regex `(?ms)^[A-Z]{3}.` matches:

> 1. `"ABC "`
> 2. `"DEF\n"`

While both `(?m)^[A-Z]{3}.` and `(?s)^[A-Z]{3}.` match:

> 1. `"ABC "`

Comment: Thanks! Could you pls explain when we can use (?ms)

Comment: When are these modes _not_ mutually exclusive. They're entirely different and unrelated.

Comment: @sln It's not true that `(?s)` and `(?m)` are "entirely different and unrelated". As Sam Holder points out in his answer, in Tcl, `(?s)` and `(?m)` block one another, but in other implementations, they don't. It's an implementation specific thing, and you can't assume that they can be used together in all regex implementations.

Comment: Then I believe that Ruby and Tcl are trying to implement the true verbal sense of the phrases single/multi line modes without actually dealing with the rich and robust uses that both can bring together at the same time. Its unfortunate. Dot-all and multi-line mode are essential tools that were designed to be mutually exclusive and used together or separately. It looks like they are crippled engine's. Hope they can fix it someday.

Comment: Marvellous article. I had stupidly thought this can never be done.

Answer (score 10):

Sometimes people say `(?s)` is single line mode. Its not, there is no such thing.
It means  the Dot meta-char `.` matches any newline, meaning the Dot matches any character.
The default is usually the Dot does **Not** match newline, so you have to specifically
set the Dot-All modifier through the regex options constant, or the inline modifier `(?s)`.

`(?m)` is the multi-line modifier. It lets the anchors `^$` match beginning/end of lines, as
well as beginning/end of string.

How/when/should  `(?ms)` be used together?
The answer is that sometimes you want to use the Dot to span newlines, while at the same time
need `^` to match at beginning of line. *And you are not to sure about anything inbetween.*

Example:

`(?ms)^BlockStart.*?BlockEnd`

where the input is:

StringStart aasdfasdffasdf
asgasgasgw fasfggasfgaag
`BlockStart asgdfasggafsdgadsfg 
aaaasfgaafdsgasfg 
afbaadsf afdsgadsfg BlockEnd` afsbgafsdgasfg
aaaaaafrgasfgaadsfgg

Comment: Do you have a source on `(?s)` not being single-line mode? According to the [man page for PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt), which is as close as modern regex has to a standard, `(?s)` is "single line (dotall)" mode.

Comment: @Tutleman - The 'Single line mode' phrase has been mis-quoted for as far back as regex has started, has nothing to do with modern regex. There is no context that means single line in regular expressions. There is context for multi-line though, meaning single-line is _not_ the inverse to multi-line. If that were the case they would cancel each other out and `(?ms)` is meaningless. I think `single-line_mode` is a verbal holdover from the notion of the record separator variable, for lack of definition. Then the `dotall` phrase started being used to avoid questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

I think these are [mode modifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html)

From the site linked it states:

- (?s) for "single line mode" makes the dot match all characters, including line breaks. Not supported by Ruby or JavaScript. In Tcl, (?s) also makes the caret and dollar match at the start and end of the string only.
- (?m) for "multi-line mode" makes the caret and dollar match at the start and end of each line in the subject string. In Ruby, (?m) makes the dot match all characters, without affecting the caret and dollar which always match at the start and end of each line in Ruby. In Tcl, (?m) also prevents the dot from matching line breaks.

I'm not 100% certain why you would want to specify multiline and single line mode at the same time, but the example on the page does it as well so maybe its valid...

Comment: Thanks. Can I apply these defn in Powershell ?

Comment: yes [I believe these can be used in powershell](http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/Powershell_regular_expressions#Mode_Modifiers).