# Match across line breaks when using -match with a regular expression

Tags: windows, powershell

The following results a single match of "foo".

```
$multilineString = "foo
    bar
         baz";

$multilineString -match ".*";

$matches;
```

That is because [the `.` character does not include line breaks](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html).

These also output only "foo".

```
$multilineString -match "(.|\r)*" | Out-Null; $matches[0];
$multilineString -match "(.|\r\n)*" | Out-Null; $matches[0];
```

In PowerShell, how do we use match to include any character including line breaks, so that the output will include all three lines:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

Comment: You would need to use `(?ms).*`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27680233/15339544) for details. Same thing applies if you're using `[regex]::Matches(...)`

Comment: If you're looking to just match the 3 words without having to trim the leading and trailing white space you can just do `[regex]::Matches($multilineString, '\w+').Value`.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Thx for the tip on `(?ms).*`. Also, for this use case, it's important that we use the `-match` operator.

Comment: I'm not sure how you would get the same result (an array with the 3 words) of `[regex]::Matches($multilineString, '\w+').Value` using `-mach` unless you're doing a `-split '\r?\n'` to the string and then looping over each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I almost never use `-match` for this specific use, as in my comment, I usually go with [`[regex]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-6.0). After reviewing the MS Docs:

> It is important to note that the `$Matches` hashtable contains only the first occurrence of any matching pattern.

So, if you want to get the same result as `[regex]::Matches($multilineString, '\w+').Value`, that would require first to split the string and then loop over it:

```
$multilineString = "foo
    bar
         baz"

$multilineString -split '\r?\n' | ForEach-Object {
    if($_ -match '\w+')
    {
        $Matches
    }   
}
```

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
0                              foo
0                              bar
0                              baz
```

An alternative that would also work and will not require a split or a loop is possible, but the `regex` pattern has to be more specific. In this case, **we know** that we're looking for 3 words.

```
$multilineString = "foo
    bar
         baz"

$multilineString -match '^(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)$'
$Matches
```

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
3                              baz
2                              bar
1                              foo
0                              foo…
```